# Помогите написать программу в си++ (без циклов и массивов)

Tags: строки

Даны целое число k (1<=k<=180 ) и последовательность цифр 101102103…149150, в которой выписаны подряд все трехзначные числа от 101 до 150. определить k -ю цифру, если известно, что: - k - число кратное трём; - k - одно из чисел 1,4,7…;- k - одно их чисел 2,5,8…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**k - число кратное трём** - значит искомое число лежит в единицах, ряд чисел будет постоянно увеличиваться на 1, а после 9 обнуляться.

```
r = (k / 3) % 10;
```

**k - одно из чисел 1,4,7…;** - есть сотни. т.е. всегда равен 1.

а с третьим примером сами разбиритесь :)